# "Кроме() как." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, как

*Что ты знаешь, кроме(,) как тратить деньги?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Что ты знаешь, кроме как тратить деньги?**

КРОМЕ КАК - составной союз, Запятой выделен оборот со значением исключения.

Пример:

Миру не останется ничего, кроме как последовать за тобой. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

Я ведь ничего не умею, кроме как снимать кино...[Алексей Учитель. «По-настоящему я верю в любовь» // «Огонек», 2014]

― И тебя выгнало из берлоги великим сквозняком, а что ты умеешь, кроме как рвать зубами хлеб из земли да пропастей шарахаться, которыми сплошь выстлана столбовая людская дорога. [Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Части 1-2 (1927)] [